# Controling how much recrocds are filled in sqldataadapter

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

I'm filling sqldataadapter with several thousand records from remote server. During that time application freezes until the fetching data is over. Sometime it tooks few minutes sometimes much longer depending about server availability so user never know how much records is downloaded and when the process will be finished. For this reason I want to implement somekind of counter how much records remains to finish download process.

This is how I fill sqldataadapter:

```
        void FillDataAdapter(string sQuery)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
            SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder;
            DataTable dataTable;

            mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, this.connection);
            mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
            mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 30;

            dataTable = new DataTable();                      
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
```

On this line application freezs until filling is done:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Fill method has int return data type but i can only get number of records in data adapter after filling is done. On which way I can get current number of records in dataadapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, but you can make use of

```
public int Fill(
    int startRecord,
    int maxRecords,
    params DataTable[] dataTables
)
```

overload fill method to get the number of record you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threadpool here to call that database connection asynchronously. Here is some link for your help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

If you use counter here, then too you have to wait until all the data has been fetched. But if you use threadpool, then you don't have to wait for execute that part of code.When this part of code executed, then other part of code will be also executed. When all the data has been fetched, you can display all the data at that moment. You don't have to worry about the not responding or server busy matter.